# moving info from one register to another using dot, powerpc

Tags: powerpc

There are three simple instructions from Power PC assembly:

```
mr. r7, r3
li r3, 0
beqlr
```

Well, if i understand here all lines correctly, i move value from register `r3` to `r9`, load `r3` with `0` and jump to address from LR (link register); dot near `mr` instruction means that i load `cr0` with information of the result of operation but what will be the value of `cr0` after moving `r3` to `r9`? and what is the condition under what i jump to the address in LR?

Answer (score 0):

`mr` is an alias for `or` so you can find the relevant information in that instruction's [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/da/aix/7.3?topic=is-instruction)

in this case, as the branching instruction nmenonic indicates, it will jump if r3 was originally 0